# Distinct count to exclude NULL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

Is there a way to create a calculated measure that can do a distinct count, but excluding the  null values? For example, if I have: 10, 20, 20, null; the distinct count is 3, but can I have the answer as 2?

Comment: Can't you eliminate the NULLs with an appropriate WHERE clause?

Comment: I did the said distinct count using the GUI's New Measure. As for creating the calculated measure, I will need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. However, here I found a solution that works best for my need: http://richardlees.blogspot.com/2008/10/alternative-to-physical-distinct-count.html

By creating a Calculated Member using the following:

```
count(nonempty({[DimName].[HierarchyName].[LevelName].members-[DimName].[HierarchyName][All].UNKNOWNMEMBER},[Measures].[MyMeasure]))
```

Comment: This also works for me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785454/in-ssas-how-to-remove-null-value-in-distinct-count-measures.

Answer (score 0):

put a where condition
to where the measure is not null

Comment: the where condition eliminates the null, but gives 3 as result - the OP asked for 2.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
with cte ( "counter" ) as
( 
    select 
        1 as "counter" 
    from 
        "YOURTABLE" 
    group by 
        "COLUMNNAME" 
    having ( "COLUMNNAME" IS NOT NULL )
)
select SUM( "counter" ) from cte
```

**@ edit:**

quite easier variant:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT "COLUMNNAME" ) FROM "TABLENAME"
```

Comment: I think the OP asked about MDX, you're talking SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue - it is amazing microsoft ignores it...looks like the only solution is to build a view for distinct count measure group

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic810069-17-1.aspx#bm1213461

Answer (score 0):

simply add where value is not null and value "!=''" that should do the trick