# IN SSAS how to remove null value in distinct count measures

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have column in `fact table` .the column in some row has `'Null'` value.i have measure based on this column with `aggregate function` Set to `DistinctCount`

this measure count `null` value too.
but i don't want to count `null` value what should i do?

Answer (score 5):

Most efficient would be to filter out NULL values in the data source view (using a named query for example). This won't affect performance too much as a distinct count measure is calculated in a separate measure group anyway.

Comment: looks like this is the only way - it is amazing microsoft ignores this problem

Answer (score 1):

One popular solution that works is to count from a view of the table that filters out the nulls.  This works, but I would bet that it requires another scan of the fact table.

Another solution is like fighting fire with fire.
Add a computed column that is 0 if it's null and 1 if it's not:

```
CASE WHEN _DollarsLY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS _DistinctCountHackLY
```

Then you can do something like this in a cube calculation:

```
iif(_DistinctCountHackLY=2 or _DollarsLY=null,_DistinctUPCLY-1,_DistinctUPCLY)
```