# How to not count the null value from a fact table in SSAS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I have many measures of distinct count in a cube. My problem is that those measures count the null value as well. I've found two solutions to eliminate the null value:

1. I've created named queries in data source view for each measure where i put the condition that the column that i need does not contains  null [where column is not null] (but this solution is not that practical, because if you have many measures, that do not need to count the null value you have to make a lot of fact tables as named queries to eliminate the null)
2. I've created an additional column as Named calculation in the fact table, where i tested if the column that i need contains null to put 1 else to put 0 (CASE WHEN Column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0). After that i created a measure of maximum on this additional column and i created a measure of distinct count on the column that i needed . And finally, i created a calculation where i tested the following: IIF([measure that i need]- [Maximum of additional column]<0,null,[measure that i need]- [Maximum of additional column])

Both solutions works but my question is if there is another solution more simple than those two mentioned or if there is an option in SSAS. 
If someone knows please share the information.

Comment: Can you not eliminate the NULL values using your WHERE clause?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914039/distinct-count-to-exclude-null

Comment: Both of your proposed solutions are commonly used. If that column for which you are counting distinct values is a foreign key to a dimension, you can use nonempty().

Answer (score -1):

In Sql it is possible to use

```
select count(column_name) from table.
```

this doesn't count the null values.

`count(*)` does count the null values.

Comment: i need in analysis services